# Angular 4: ngComponentOutlet with ContentChildren

Tags: forms, angular, dynamic, ng-component-outlet

I have a question about dynamic forms. The current situation is that we have a template driven form and the requirement is that the user can reorder the controls and also set some to invisible. For reordering we use dragula but for loading the stored setting we need to generate the form dynamically. We want to keep the template driven aproach and now my idea was to use the ngComponentOutlet in combination with the ContentChildren of the template to generate the form with the stored setting. Is this possible does anyone have another idea ? If possible please provide an example.